# Parent-Child parameters in SSIS 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Is it possible to create Parent-child parameters in SSIS 2012  like in SSIS 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. By default when you create a new project for SQL Server 2012/2014/2016, it is going to use the Project Deployment Model. You will right click on the project and select Package Deployment Model and then you will be able to do all of the things you were doing in 2008 (logging, configuration, etc)

Comment: Thanks you ,after changing the Project Deployment model to package deployment model can i still deploy the packages in Integration services catalog  ? do i  need to make any changes ?

Comment: Package Deployment Model can be deployed to MSDB or to the file system as usual. Project Deployment Model is deployed to the SSISDB